# "You are" vs. "you're" — what is the difference between them?

Tags: formality, contractions, spoken-english, register

“You are” vs. “you're” — what is the difference between them?

I get confused between the two *a lot*. I want to understand how to use them appropriately, because I hate making mistakes.

Comment: There is no difference. _You are_ is normally contracted to _you're_ in speech, because English doesn't like two vowels without a consonant to separate them, and one of them gets deleted. Either _you're_ or _you are_ can be used; speaker's choice. The same thing applies to _I'm, he's, she's, we're,_ and _they're_, among other contractions. It's just colloquial English, that's all.

Comment: If there *is* a difference (outside of the most formal usage), it is that *you are* (and other forms that don't use contractions) are more emphatic and separable. ***You** are going to be doing it* makes a slightly different point from *You **are** going to be doing it*.

Comment: @JohnLawler I’m betting that non-native speakers are seldom taught that many such “contractions” occur naturally in speaking because of reduction of unstressed pieces — more than we write, in fact. (Like in *“I’ll’ve given ’er another chance by then.”*) And that they all originated in that fashion.

Comment: I'm wondering if you actually meant to ask about the difference between "your" and "you're".

Comment: @Marthaª Good question!  If so, then it is a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3738.

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference in meaning although there are a few differences in usages. Here, there is virtually no difference:

> You are flying to Belgium tomorrow.
>   You're flying to Belgium tomorrow.

However, there are places where the two are not interchangeable. For example, this particular contraction cannot be used at the end of a sentence, or as a standalone sentence:

> Who is flying to Belgium tomorrow?
>   **CORRECT ANSWER**: You are, Tim.
>   **INCORRECT ANSWER**: You're, Tim.

The same principles hold true for the other related contractions:

I'm ➝ I am
He's ➝ He is
They're ➝ They are
We're ➝ We are

Answer (score 2):

You are and You're are the same. You're is the contraction of You are.

[dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/you're?s=t)

However, in formal writing it is more appropriate to use "You are" as opposed to "You're".

Comment: That depends on the formality and the level of relationship. No matter what your English teacher told you.